# How to integrate redux-form with redux-observable

Tags: redux-form, react-redux-form

I am very new to redux and redux-observable so I would like to ask for some advice.

I am using redux-observable with rxjs to handle all my side effects which works very well.

I am using redux-form to handle form input and form validation that works also very well.

My problem is to integrate them together. My understanding is that redux-observable runs parallel to my ordinary actions creators so the action I invoke when I submit the form will always return without an error and my parallel running observable will yield a different action down the line if there was any issue with the submittion so I am not sure how I could handle it properly.

I found the following library. https://github.com/salsita/redux-form-actions
that looks like using a HOC to wrap the action with a promise. I am just wondering if that is the right way to go about it and how it works.

Can someone from the redux-form community check it out and let me know if it looks good. I do not have enough knowledge to make a call at this point as I wrote my first form today and I do not with to go down the wrong path.

Also an explanation how this works would be gratelly appreciated too / if there is a better approach.

I appreciate any comment or notes!

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Only that I has found about right way to integrate is [this](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/161#issuecomment-191312502) link from [this thread](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/87)

Answer (score 0):

The gist is, within `onSubmit`, pass a `Promise`'s `resolve`/`reject` functions to a dispatched action.  `await` on that promise.  then, in your epic, call resolve/reject as needed to resume `onSubmit`'s flow.

here's my PR explaining how it works, with a runnable example: https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/pull/490